# php pdo not updating table

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, sql-update

Iv been at this for hours, and it still wont work

i am trying to update a table

im not getting any errors

this is the account

```
<?php
                      if(isset($_POST['editfirst'])){

                        $delivery_option = $_POST['delivery_option'];

                        $about = $_POST['about'];


                        $SharersSignup->updateProfile($delivery_option);

                        echo 'ok';

                        }
                      ?>
```

this is the function

```
$query = $this->pdo->prepare('UPDATE `sharers` SET delivery_option = ?, WHERE random = ?');

        $query->bindValue(1, $delivery_option);
        $query->bindValue(2, $_SESSION['logkey']);

        try {
           $query->execute();
        }
        catch(Exception $e) {
            echo 'Exception -> ';
            var_dump($e->getMessage());
        }
```

Comment: Remove the comma `SET delivery_option = ?,` <=

Comment: i have literally been at this for hours haha, thanks it now works :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you have a trailing comma in `SET delivery_option = ?,` <=

Remove it.